# Jquery UI Draggable clone in same ul or div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, clone, jquery-ui-draggable

While implementing functionality of clone I found that the li is always created on the end and any li is created with only drag of another li without dropping into any particular position. I am unable to implement a li clone on the next of the mother help. Here are the reference I found and the demo as follows.

Referrences

[how to initiate .clone using drag & drop or click jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21870841/how-to-initiate-clone-using-drag-drop-or-click-jquery)

[javascript - how to make multiple draggable clones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055184/javascript-how-to-make-multiple-draggable-clones)

I am unable to run demo on the Jsfiddle so I am putting the whole code here.

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    li {
    border:1px dashed Gainsboro;
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    color:FloralWhite;
    font-family:Cursive;
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    margin:2px;
}

ul {
    border:1px solid PowderBlue;
    min-height:50px;

}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#list-A li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
$('#list-A ul').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.data('sorting'))
            return;
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }
}).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.data('sorting', true);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeData('sorting');
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body style="cursor: auto;">
  <div id="list-A">
    <ul class="sortable2">
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-draggable">drag item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? I changed your css from `float:left` to `display:inline-block' so that your parent element will scale with the cloned `li's`.  Currently if you drag an original `li` it will clone without sorting functionality, but then the clone will be sortable.  Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/VR2wz/  What exactly are you looking for?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you would like it both Clone-able and Sort-able

```
$('#list-A ul').sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.before(ui.helper.clone().attr('style',''));
        ui.item.data('sorting', true);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeData('sorting');
    }
});
```

Example:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/LSgs5/)

Comment: But there is a problem. I am unable to cancel copying if I have started dragging

Comment: @Soumya How would you expect to cancel dragging, or what are you trying to do to cancel dragging?

Comment: @Soumya I'm not sure what your looking for but here is an example where if you hold the `alt` key down when dropping the sortable it will cancel it.  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/LSgs5/1/

Comment: Yes that make sense. Thanks Travor. It solved all of my requirements. Yes I wanted that altkey stop function. Thanks again.